# Finding the right range from excel table

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

[image: Image from the table]

What is the best way to find the right column for the **travelled miles** using visual basic coding or some excel function and return the **price** from that column? `HLOOKUP` can't be used here because the lookup value isn't exact and the ranges in the table are also not with specific intervals (If they were, I could use e.g. `FLOOR(travelled miles/100)*100` and find the price with `HLOOKUP`). Obviously, it's easy to find the price manually with a small table but with a big table computer will be faster.

Comment: If you go 6 miles, it's still $10/mile for the first 5 miles, per the first-tier price, right?

Comment: If so, it's not quite as simple a calculation as you say -- and if not, that's a bizarre policy because when the odometer rolls over from 499 to 500 miles, the driver just lost almost $1000 in reimbursement (from 499*5 to 500*3), right?

Comment: If it's 6 miles then it's 6miles*9$/miles = $54. The price per mile are relatively random. The main point is that I want to know is how to code it to look the right price/mile.

Comment: Why would an Hlookup not work here? If you remove the dash at the end of your Row 1 values and use `=hlookup(B5,B1:G2,2,TRUE)` it will return `5`. Note that the last parameter "Range Lookup" in the `Hlookup` funciton will essentially act as your `FLOOR` for the range lookup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to find the price without removing the dash from the table?

Comment: Unfortunately not that I can think of. You could have a second row that trims the hyphen and do your `hlookup` from that row. Something like `=left(B1, len(b1)-1)` could be used for the trim.

Comment: `=left(B1, len(b1)-1)` doesn't work with Hlookup. I tried and Hlookup accepts only numbers not formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, if `x` is between `a` and `b`, then `MEDIAN(x,a,b)=x`. Combine this with some nested IFs:

```
=IF(MEDIAN(B5,B1,C1-1)=B5,B2,IF(MEDIAN(B5,C1,D1-1)=B5,C2,IF(MEDIAN(B5,D1,E1-1)=B5,D2)))
```

I'm on my phone, so just done the first three cases, but hopefully you can see how it continues.

(should note you need to remove the dashes for this to work)

**Edit:**

I also want to answer your question in the comments above. You can use the following to keep the dash, but get a number to work with.

Assume cell A1 has got the value `10-`. We can use the `FIND` function to work out where the `-` occurs and then use the `LEFT` function to only return the characters from before the dash:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)
```

This will return the value `10`, but it will return it as a string, not a number - basically Excel will think it is text. To force Excel to consider it as a number, we can simply multiply the value by one. Our formula above therefore becomes:

```
=(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1))*1
```

You may also see people use a double minus sign, like this:

```
=--LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)
```

I don't recommend this because it's a bit complex, but combining with the formula above would give:

```
=IF(MEDIAN(B5,--LEFT(B1,FIND("-",B1)-1),--LEFT(C1,FIND("-",C1)-1)-1)=B5,B2,IF(MEDIAN(B5,--LEFT(C1,FIND("-",C1)-1,--LEFT(D1,FIND("-",D1)-1-1)=B5,C2,IF(MEDIAN(B5,--LEFT(D1,FIND("-",D1)-1,--LEFT(E1,FIND("-",E1)-1-1)=B5,D2)))
```